# How to configure jest with typescript with decorators project running on build (compiled) code

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

Assume I have a typescript project and I use decorators.
Out dir is "build".
I want to test the compiled code, not the source code, so my test pattern include "build".
I don't see reason using ts-jest since the code was already compiled

But when I run Jest (remember on build code) it failes with error
SyntaxError: /.../models/externalEntity.model.ts: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators' isn't currently enabled (6:1):

I tried to configure

```js
  transform: {
    "\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": [
      "babel-jest",
      {
        decoratorsBeforeExport: true,
        plugins: [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators",
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

but it still fail with different error related to decorators

my jest config and tsconfig are:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "node",
  rootDir: "./build",
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/**/integration/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)']
}
```

```js
{
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",                     
    "lib": ["es2019", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true, 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "traceResolution": false,
    "extendedDiagnostics": false
  },
}
```